# Laravel notification with one notification class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my web app I have added the notification functionalities.

There are 3 notification class.
App/Notifications/

1. NotifWhenLiked.php
2. NotifyWhenStoryCommented.php
3. NotifyWhenAuthorFollowed.php

**I want to make these task with one single Notification class. Is there any easiest way to solve this ?**

Here is the code of one class

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Http\Resources\Users;
use App\Model\User;
use App\Model\Story;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NotifyWhenLiked extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $user;
    public $story;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Story $story, User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->story = $story;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database','broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [

                'notification' => "<strong>".$this->user->name."</strong>". ' liked your story '. "<strong>".$this->story->title."</strong>",
                'Storylink' => '/story/'.$this->story->url_key,
                'Userlink' => '/a/'.$this->user->profile->username

    ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [

                'notification' => $this->user->name. ' liked your story '. "<strong>".$this->story->title."</strong>",
                'username' => $this->user->profile->username,

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: If all classes perform similar function, then just keep one class and remove the others. You would anyways have to change all code which dispatches those notifications manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to store the different notification types into an array e.g. a config file.

```
return [
   'when_liked' => [
      'notification_text' => '%s liked your story %s',
      'story_link' => '/story/%s'
   ],
   'when_commented' => [
      'notification_text' => '%s commented on your story %s',
      'story_link' => '/story/%s'
   ]
]
```

You can make a general Notification Class, which takes care about handling the notification stuff.

```
$whenLikedNotification = new YourCustomNotificationClass('when_liked');
$whenLikedNotification->trigger();
```

In the Constructor you can handle the config stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a event to do it

Create a event and call all listener(`WhenLiked, WhenStoryCommented, WhenAuthorFollowed`) that is related with event